# Dynamically change a NamedQuery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have a query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE mt.firstCondition = :var1
AND mt.secondCondition = :var2
```

var1 is an Integer and var2 is a String. I want to discard the condition for var1, if I receive -1 on it. So, if var1 is anything bellow zero, the query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE mt.secondCondition = :var2
```

Can I make that change on a NamedQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate parses named queries at startup which is what gives the performance boost as Hibernate doesn't have to do it each time the query is executed. So what I'm saying is you can't dynamically change a named query, it will defeat its purpose if you could. What you can do is place some conditions in your named query in question to cater for your needs. Luis LL provided you the condition so I wont repeat.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE (mt.firstCondition = :var1 OR :var1 = -1) AND mt.secondCondition = :var2
```

Comment: -1 is not a valid value. When I receive -1, it means I have to return results for every value on this field. That's why I need to get rid of that condition.

Comment: that's the same reason I'm forcing it true in the right side of the OR (mt.fisrtCondition = :var1 **OR :var1 = -1**)